# Add negative number to unsigned short in C

Tags: c, binary, hex, twos-complement, negative-number

Basically I am writing code in C to convert some lc-3 instructions from a text file into binary and then outputting it in hex. I've reached the point where I need to add a decimal number. I have no problem doing this with positive numbers but I have no idea how to go about doing it with negative numbers. I realise I will have to convert to two's complement but I have no idea how to go about doing this as I am very new to C. Any advice or hints would be greatly appreciated. Apologies in advance for formatting errors with my code. Not very experienced with SO editor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char line[40];
        unsigned short bin;
        char operator[10], destination[10], source1[10], source2[10];

        FILE *file; if((file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
                printf("IO Error, please specify a file\n");

        }
        else{
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while(fgets(line, 40, file) != NULL){
        sscanf(line, "%s %[^,],%[^,],%s",operator,destination,source1,source2);
        if(strcmp(operator,"add")==0){
                bin = 0b0001000000000000;
        }
        if(strcmp(operator,"and")==0){
                bin = 0b0101000000000000;
        }
        bin+=(destination[1]-'0') * 0b1000000000;
        bin+=(source1[1]-'0') * 0b1000000;
        char *dec=strstr(source2,"r");
        if (dec){
        bin+=(source2[1] - '0');
        }
        else{

        bin+=0b100000;
        int source2Dec ;
        sscanf(source2,"%d",&source2Dec);
        bin+=(source2Dec);
        }

        printf("%x\n", bin);
        }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Remember you can see what your post will look like in the preview down of the editor. Simply put you only need to offset your line 4 characters to the right in order for it to be considered code. Concerning your problem: What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I was trying to figure it out sorry about that I hope it's still legible. Basically it's converting lc-3 instructions to hex. With this part, I need to make it so it is capable of dealing with decimals so that it can handle instructions like: add r6,r7,-9 but I have no idea how to deal with the -9 with the binary. Positive numbers are working fine but I'm guessing I need to do something with two's complement to get negatives to work

Comment: So your problem is, in fact, [substracting two binary numbers](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+to+substract+binary+numbers)?

Comment: No. The problem is I need to represent binary in hex. I need to convert -9 to binary and do it with two's complement. I can get 9 in binary but then I need to flip the bits and add 1 to get -9. I don't know how to do that process in C. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So your problem is [how to convert a negative number to binary](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+to+convert+negative+number+in+binary) ?

Comment: You seem to mix up things. `unsigned` integer types have an internal binary representation, but this doesn't mean that you have to use binary constants to compute with them. If you want `-9` to be represented in two's complement and print it as hex, just assign it to an `unsigned short` (this does all the arithmetic for you) and then print it with format `%hx`